# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kmodes'

Tags: python

I have tried installing it using pip install kmodes and it says that "Requirement is satisfied" but am not being able to import the library even after that.

The list of libraries doesn't have kmodes even after installing. Attaching screenshot for reference. What is happening here?

```
from kmodes.kprototypes import KPrototypes

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kmodes'
```

[image]

Comment: If it's python 3, try "pip3 install kmodes"

Comment: tried that, same thing is happening

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your PIP is installing to the wrong version of python and the code you are running is being interreted by a later version
Try copying your python executable path and running this

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe -m pip install kmodes
```

Another reason is that kmodes did not install properly the first time
Try running this as an administrator

```
pip uninstall kmodes && pip install kmodes
```